# .htaccess rewriteEngine with multiple get variables

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to change a url with multiple variables, for example this url:

```
index.php?p=place&c=Munich
```

to:

```
/place/munich
```

with .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&c=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: ahh yeah your script works great, but no single link in my application is now correct. Is there a way to fix this from the .htaccess?

Comment: i meant that not a single link in the whole app is correct when i open the new url :D sry

Comment: Oh I had a typo in my rule that I have fixed now. Can you try again. Also make sure to use use use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`

Comment: yeah i found the problem, there was a error with the variable that included the full http path. now its working fine. Thank you

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: i tried to add another variable to my url. for now i used this .htaccess:

 `RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /projects_xampp/folder/index.php?p=$1&c=$2 [L,QSA]`

i tried to change it to this code but it is not working:


`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /projects_xampp/folder/index.php?p=$1&c=$2&pl=$3 [L,QSA]`


can you help me with my problem?

Comment: It is very difficult to read code from comments. Can you create a new question with this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280232/htaccess-rewrite-engine-with-more-than-2-variables

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what characters those two parameters contain, here's one for only letters (a-zA-Z):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?p=$1&c=$2
```